# Guard let construction, still getting fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to parse some data with this code:

```
func findDate(data: String?) -> String {
    guard let date: String? = (data!.componentsSeparatedByString("T"))[0] else{
        return "20000101"
    }
    return date!
}
```

I tried the guard structure to prevent errors when there is no data found, or it has a different structure, but I still get the error when I run it:

fatal error: Index out of range

Does somebody know how to fix this?

Comment: Could you give us the calling syntax?

Comment: While the `guard let` is interesting, could you issue be more about parsing a date and use a dateformatter instead?

Comment: findDate("20170707T141500Z") Salman

Comment: But I also need to fix this problem for other functions where I used the guard let structure. Problem is no that it tells me "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: @JanMarkDannenberg Plz checks out my answer below let me know if you have any confusion.!

Comment: `findDate("20170707T141500Z")` => Use a DateFormatter.

Answer (score 2):

The access of the element at index zero always happens. If the result of the call to `components(separatedBy:)` returns an empty array, your code crashes. Also, you should avoid force unwrapping `data`.

A solution to these crashes is to use the `first` property of the array, which is optional, so you can safely unwrap it.

```
guard let date = data?.components(separatedBy: "T").first else {
    return "20000101"
}
return date.
```

Also, this could then be simplified using the nil coalescing operator:

```
return data?.components(separatedBy: "T").first ?? "20000101"
```

Comment: func findDate(data: String?) -> String {
    guard let date: String? = (data!.componentsSeparatedByString("T")).first else{
        return "20000101"
    }
    return date!
}

Comment: But now it gives me another error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this code:

```
func findDate(data: String?) -> String {
    guard let date: String? = (data?.componentsSeparatedByString("T"))?[0] else{
        return "20000101"
    }
    return date!
}

findDate(nil)
findDate("")
findDate("98588T99")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

1) Trying to access an index of an array that isn't large enough doesn't produce `nil`, it just crashes. For example, this code will crash:

```
let strings: [String] = []
guard let firstString = strings[0] else {
    // couldn't find firstString
}
```

Instead, use the `first` method:

```
let strings: [String] = []
guard let firstString = strings.first else {
    // couldn't find firstString
}
```

`first` attempts to access the first element of the array, and it returns `nil` if the array doesn't have a first element.

2) The purpose of `guard let` is to guarantee that the value you get out isn't `nil`. So your `date` value should be of type `String`, not `String?`, and you shouldn't have to force-unwrap it. For example:

```
let strings: [String] = ["one", "two", "three"]
guard let firstString = strings.first else {
    // no first string
}
print(firstString) // firstString is not nil, no need to unwrap it
```